# Segmentation fault while compiling the customised malloc.c library

Tags: c, linux, pointers, struct, malloc

The only thing i modified in the library was the malloc_chunk struct. i just added another variable to the malloc_chunk struct. after which while compiling shows segmentation fault.

A part from the malloc.c library

```
/* -----------------------  Chunk representations ------------------------ */
struct malloc_chunk {
  size_t               prev_foot;  /* Size of previous chunk (if free).  */
  size_t               head;       /* Size and inuse bits. */
  size_t               fulan;
  struct malloc_chunk* fd;         /* double links -- used only if free.     */
  struct malloc_chunk* bk;

};
```

fulan is the variable which i added. i cant figure out why i am getting segmentation fault. Any help is appreciated :(

Comment: Not enough context.

Comment: i want my variable "fulan" to be present in the header of the memory block allocated using malloc function .

Comment: so i was editing the malloc_chunk struct of malloc.c library

Comment: Add that field after `bk` and see if that works.  Not sure if malloc has any pointer arithmetic based on the current structure.

Comment: @codeforester good guess. See for one example the definition of `mem2chunk`.

Comment: @codeforester it worked (y). but now when compiling the user program i get the error "Aborted (core dumped)" :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added that field after bk and it worked (y)